# Calculate timestamp(dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss) difference in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a form in HTML which generates the start time(dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss) and end time(dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss) in text box. User can modify them, if required. Then upon click on textbox for time spent should display the difference of the start and end time in minutes.
I am using javascript to calculate the time difference by calling the function onlick. But it is not working. Can somebody help me with this?

```
function diffDateTime(startDT,endDT)
{
if(typeof startDT == 'string' && startDT.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[amp ]{0,3}$/i)){

    startDT = startDT.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}/);
    startDT = startDT.toString().split(':');
    var obstartDT = new Date();
    obstartDT.setHours(startDT[0]);
    obstartDT.setMinutes(startDT[1]);
    obstartDT.setSeconds(startDT[2]);
  }
else if(typeof startDT == 'string' && startDT.match(/^now$/i)) var obstartDT = new Date();
  else if(typeof startDT == 'string' && startDT.match(/^tomorrow$/i)){
    var obstartDT = new Date();
    obstartDT.setHours(24);
    obstartDT.setMinutes(0);
    obstartDT.setSeconds(1);
  }
  else var obstartDT = new Date(startDT);

  if(typeof endDT == 'string' && endDT.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[amp ]{0,3}$/i)){

    endDT = endDT.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}/);
    endDT = endDT.toString().split(':');
    var obendDT = new Date();
    obendDT.setHours(endDT[0]);
    obendDT.setMinutes(endDT[1]);
    obendDT.setSeconds(endDT[2]);
  }

  else if(typeof endDT == 'string' && endDT.match(/^now$/i)) var obendDT = new Date();

  else if(typeof endDT == 'string' && endDT.match(/^tomorrow$/i)){

    var obendDT = new Date();
    obendDT.setHours(24);
    obendDT.setMinutes(0);
    obendDT.setSeconds(1);
  }
  else var obendDT = new Date(endDT);

  // gets the difference in number of seconds
  // if the difference is negative, the hours are from different days, and adds 1 day (in sec.)
  var secondsDiff = (obendDT.getTime() - obstartDT.getTime()) > 0 ? (obendDT.getTime() - obstartDT.getTime()) / 1000 :  (86400000 + obendDT.getTime() - obstartDT.getTime()) / 1000;
  secondsDiff = Math.abs(Math.floor(secondsDiff));

  var oDiff = {};     // object that will store data returned by this function

  oDiff.days = Math.floor(secondsDiff/86400);
  oDiff.totalhours = Math.floor(secondsDiff/3600);      // total number of hours in difference
  oDiff.totalmin = Math.floor(secondsDiff/60);      // total number of minutes in difference
  oDiff.totalsec = secondsDiff;      // total number of seconds in difference

  secondsDiff -= oDiff.days*86400;
  oDiff.hours = Math.floor(secondsDiff/3600);     // number of hours after days

  secondsDiff -= oDiff.hours*3600;
  oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(secondsDiff/60);     // number of minutes after hours

  secondsDiff -= oDiff.minutes*60;
  oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(secondsDiff);     // number of seconds after minutes

  return oDiff;

}

function calcmin(startts,endts) {

  var startts = document.getElementById("startcurrenttime").value;

  var endts = document.getElementById("endcurrenttime").value;

  var objDiff = diffDateTime(startts,endts);

  var dtdiff = objDiff.days+ ' days, '+ objDiff.hours+ ' hours, '+ objDiff.minutes+ ' minutes, '+ objDiff.seconds+ ' seconds';

  var total_min = objDiff.totalmin;

  document.getElementById('testdtdiff').innerHTML += total_min;

}
```

Comment: Please post your javascript code, and specify what exactly isn't working.  Is it the calculation or the actual call of the function on `onclick`?

Comment: I am facing the actual call of the function on click. <td valign="top"><input type="text" onclick="calcmin(startcurrenttime,endcurrenttime);" name="testdtdiff" id="testdtdiff" /></td>